# Why does changing how a bisection search is implemented make a runtime difference between two solutions to the same problem?

Tags: python

while going through a [python programming problem](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-0001-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-in-python-fall-2016/8cf75481d7047180c386de3e485bd050_MIT6_0001F16_ps1.pdf) from an MIT course, I got stuck trying to figure out the difference between two solutions, or more specifically, the reason behind why changing a part of the code made it run faster, while the original solution took so long that it kept on running (no infinite loop) and never delivered an output.

1. My solution that ran forever and did not give an output:

```
def bisection(i: int, j: int):
    """
    Inputs: Integers, 'i' and 'j', representing the lower limit and the upper limit of the search.
    Returns: Bisects the number of possibilites and returns the middle value.
    """
    high = j
    low = i

    return (high+low)/2



semiannualraise = .07
rmonthly = 0.04/12
cost = 1_000_000
downpayment = cost*0.25
epsilon = 100
savings = 0
nummonths = 0
startingsalary = float(input("Enter Salary: "))

high = 10000
low = 0
portion_salary= 0
step = 0
salary = startingsalary
monthly_salary=salary/12

while True:
    nummonths = 0
    salary = startingsalary
    while nummonths<36:
        portion_of_salary = (bisection(low,high))/10000
        step += 1
        savings = ((salary/12)*portion_of_salary)+(savings*rmonthly)
        nummonths +=1
        if nummonths % 6 == 0:
            salary = salary + (semiannualraise*salary)
    
    if downpayment-savings < 100 and downpayment-savings >= 0:
        break
    elif downpayment-savings>= 100:
        low = portion_of_salary*10000
    else:
        high = portion_of_salary*10000

print(f"Best savings rate: {portion_of_salary*100}%")
```

2. [Solution by Linus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67691361/finding-the-right-amount-to-save-away)

```
annual_salary = float(input('Enter the starting salary: '))
constant = annual_salary
semi_annual_rate = 0.07
r = 0.04
down_payment = 0.25
total_cost = 1000000
current_savings = 0
months = 0
bisection_count = 0
min = 0 
max = 1
portion_saved = (max/2.0)/1000
    
if(annual_salary*3<down_payment*total_cost):
    print('It is not possible to pay the down payment in three years.')

while(True):
    while(months<36):
        current_savings += (current_savings*r/12)+(portion_saved*(annual_salary/12))
        months+=1
        if(months % 6 == 0):
            annual_salary += annual_salary*semi_annual_rate
    if(current_savings >= down_payment*total_cost+100):
        max = portion_saved
        portion_saved = max/2.0
        bisection_count+=1
        months = 0
        current_savings = 0
        annual_salary = constant
    elif(current_savings >= down_payment*total_cost-100 and current_savings <= down_payment*total_cost+100):
        break
    else:
        min = portion_saved
        portion_saved = (max+min)/2.0
        bisection_count+=1
        months = 0
        current_savings = 0
        annual_salary = constant

print('Best savings rate: ', portion_saved)
print('Steps in bisection search: ', bisection_count)
```

In my opinion, the difference is made only by the way we define our limits for the bisection search, and I am unable to quite get my head around what's happening there.

Note: Though I have been using stackoverflow for about a year to look for solutions, this would be my first ever post on here and its possible that I failed to ask a great question in accordance with [How to ask a good question- StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:%7E:text=How%20do%20I%20ask%20a%20good%20question%3F%201,Respond%20to%20feedback%20after%20posting%20...%20More%20items). If so, please bear with me and also let me know what mistakes I made. Thank you.

I tried the following implementation for the bisection search:

```
def bisection(i: int, j: int):
    """
    Inputs: Integers, 'i' and 'j', representing the lower limit and the upper limit of the search.
    Returns: Bisects the number of possibilities and returns the middle value.
    """
    high = j
    low = i

    return (high+low)/2
```

and later:

```
high = 10000
low = 0
```

and then:

```
elif downpayment-savings>= 100:
        low = portion_of_salary*10000
    else:
        high = portion_of_salary*10000
```

and expected the same outputs as the other solution, but the code kept on running forever.

Comment: I’m guessing it’s not running too slow but instead the while loop is not being stopped. I’m gonna play around with it and see if I can answer before someone else, but I don’t see it just from reading

Comment: One obvious problem is the `if` sequence that starts with `if downpayment-savings < 100:`.  If that condition is true, the loop exits.  Otherwise, it performs a redundant test which must be true at that point, i.e. `elif downpayment-savings>= 100:`.  The final `else` is therefore dead code, and the assignment to `high` is never executed.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @BH10001 Okay, please keep me updated.

Comment: @TomKarzes, yes, that was done intentionally and is not dead code if we take into account a circumstance where, for a certain value of portion_salary, the total savings may exceed the downpayment in 36 months and hence the difference, (downpayment-savings) will come out to be negative, which won't fall under any of the other two test cases and will also require us to decrease the upper cap of the bisection to the current value of portion_salary.

Comment: @stucknugget If it's negative, then it will be `< 100` and hence the first test will be true and the loop will exit.  Do you understand that for any real value, if it isn't `< 100`, then it *must* be `>= 100`?  One of the two cases will always hold (unless it's a `NaN` or some other error value).  So, yes, the final else is dead.

Comment: @TomKarzes my head for some reasons skipped that. I get your point now. Let me try and see if changing that fixes the problem. That could be the problem source as that's one more thing that's done differently in the solution that works.

Comment: @TomKarzes though I was wondering, if that should matter. Wouldn't the program break from that loop and Provide an output either way(even if it's incorrect)? Am I missing something?

Comment: @stucknugget If the difference is `>= 100` then it will keep looping.  If it's ever `< 100` then the loop will break.  I'm not saying this is the only problem with code.  I'm just saying that, as posted, it couldn't possibly do what you want.

Comment: @TomKarzes You are completely correct, and I realize what you mean. The issue is, I fixed that part of the code, and it still does not give an output. I am just trying to figure out the "main problem", that is, I am trying to know why it doesn't give an output. I also tried a different approach to the problem and this time I get an output, but for some reasons the accuracy of that output is not what I am trying, I will start a new post for that problem.

Comment: @stucknugget I think you need to analyze your math.  I haven't looked at it in detail, but if your loop is never exiting, then it must mean that `downpayment-savings>= 100` is always true.  So you keep updating `low`, but `savings` is never high enough to force a loop exit.  You need to simply go through the math.  If you want to debug it, start by printing `savings` on each loop iteration, and watch how it changes.  Then you can figure out when it remains too low for the loop to exit.  Do the work.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks a lot! I tried debugging the code by printing the savings, the portion and the salary at different points and I finally figured at least why the code does not give a solution and I have to admit that the error is kind of embarrassing. I will add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging, I found out the reason the first code does not give an output is not that it runs slow, but in fact enters an infinite loop in this part:

```
while nummonths<36:
    portion_of_salary = (bisection(low,high))/10000
    step += 1
    savings = ((salary/12)*portion_of_salary)+(savings*rmonthly)
    nummonths +=1
    if nummonths % 6 == 0:
        salary = salary + (semiannualraise*salary)

if downpayment-savings < 100 and downpayment-savings >= 0:
    break
elif downpayment-savings>= 100:
    low = portion_of_salary*10000
else:
    high = portion_of_salary*10000
```

The program never exits this while loop because it never gets to the break condition, i.e, variable savings never exceeds variable downpayment.

The part causing this issue is at:

```
savings = ((salary/12)*portion_of_salary)+(savings*rmonthly)
```

Here, instead of incrementing the savings every month, the program assigns it to a new value every iteration and the savings never accumulates.

The fix is to simply add the missing '+' before '=':

```
savings += ((salary/12)*portion_of_salary)+(savings*rmonthly)
```